# Why a field is copied automatically when it's not explicitly copied while overloading assignment operator?

Tags: c++, class

I was implementing a class for Linked List and while overloading the assignment operator for this class, the weird thing happened. I copied everything over while overloading. Everything works fine. Now I commented out
code that copies the 'size' over. It still works fine! Now I'm confused.
I tried the same thing with char and std::string (and even another int) but I couldn't reaped the magic.
Can anyone tell me why?
(I used the 'size' field to keep track of the length of the list. )

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class LinkedListNode {
public:
    int value;
    LinkedListNode* p_next;
    ~LinkedListNode() {
        delete p_next;
    }
};

class LinkedList {
public:
    LinkedList()
        : size(0), p_head(nullptr)
    {}
    ~LinkedList() {
        delete p_head;
    }

    /* insert a new node at the end of the list with a given value */
    void insert(int value) {
        LinkedListNode* node = new LinkedListNode();
        node->value = value;
        node->p_next = nullptr;

        LinkedListNode* counter = p_head;
        while (true) {
            if (counter == nullptr) {  /* for empty list */
                p_head = node;
                break;
            }
            if (counter->p_next == nullptr) { /* for non-empty list */
                counter->p_next = node;
                break;
            }
            counter = counter->p_next;
        }
        size++;
    }
    int length() {
        return size;
    }
    LinkedList& operator= (const LinkedList& other) {
        // when assigning to itself
        if (this == &other) { return *this; /* to keep the chain assignment alive */ }

        // free the old memory 'cause it's no longer used
        delete p_head;
        p_head = nullptr;

        // copy everything over
        LinkedListNode* counter = other.p_head;
        while (counter != nullptr) {
            insert(counter->value);
            counter = counter->p_next;
        }
        // size = other.size;

        return *this;
    }
    void displayValues() {
        LinkedListNode* counter = p_head;
        while (counter != NULL) {
            std::cout << " " << counter->value << " ";
            counter = counter->p_next;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    LinkedListNode* p_head;
    int size; // and why am I copied automatically??
};
int main() {
    LinkedList first_list;
    first_list.insert(34);
    first_list.insert(56);
    first_list.insert(45);

    std::cout << first_list.length() << std::endl;

    LinkedList second_list;
    second_list = first_list;

    // shoudn't it print 0 ?? Because I didn't copy 'size' field
    // while overloading = operator.
    std::cout << second_list.length() << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: i suggest you to explain to your rubber duck what you do in the `operator=`, specifically the part where you call `insert` to populate the copied linked list

Comment: Aren't you incrementing size in the insert function? and you are calling insert in your overloaded assignment operator?

Comment: btw if `second_list` had items before you call `=` you would leak quite some memory, as you only `delete` its `head`

Comment: Also, since your `LinkedListNode` and `LinkedList` each have a destructor, they should also have at least a copy constructor and assignment defined or deleted, and possibly also a move constructor and move assignment. See [The Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Yeah thanks, I didn't notice the increment of size inside insert inside operator= the the first time. Now got it. 
And @user463035818, if second_list had items before I call =, I WOULDN'T leak a damn memory. Yes I deleted only it's head. But the LinkedListNode class has it's own destructor which will invoke a recursive destructor call freeing all the allocated memory until it hits nullptr (at which point it will do nothing - acts quite well as base case)

Comment: seems like you could benefit from learning how to use a debugger ;)

Comment: ah ok, for some reason I thought `p_head` is a raw pointer. Nevertheless you need to consider the rule of 3/5, currently writing `LinkedListNode second_list = first_list;` is sufficient to create problems. And btw no reason to start SHOUTING ;)